# How to create a type (named or anonymous) which is another type with some of its properties set to non-optional?

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have the following type:

```
interface Person {
  name: string,
  // ... a whole lot of other properties...
  bio?: string 
}
```

What is the best way of creating another type based on Person but with the `bio` property being non-optional?

This is what I'm currently doing for creating a named type:

```
interface PersonWithBio extends Person {
  bio: NonNullable<Person['bio']>
}
let personWithBio1: PersonWithBio;
```

And for creating an anonymous type:

```
let personWithBio2: Person & { bio: NonNullable<Person['bio']> }
```

Is there a better way without having to manually overwrite the `bio` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [mapped types with modifiers](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers):

```js
interface Person {
  name: string,
  age: number,
  bio?: string,
  bio2?: string;
  bio3?: string;
}

type WithNonOptional<T, Key extends keyof T> = T & { [K in Key]-?: T[K] };

type Person2 = WithNonOptional<Person, 'bio' | 'bio2'>;

// equivalent to:
// type Person2 = Person & {
//   bio: string;
//   bio2: string;
// }
```

This will make the `bio` and `bio2` keys non-optional but let `bio3` remain optional.

To make *all* fields non optional, there's a snippet in the docs linked above:

```js
type Concrete<Type> = {
  [Property in keyof Type]-?: Type[Property];
};

type Person3 = Concrete<Person>;

// equivalent to:
// type Person3 = {
//  name: string;
//  age: number;
//  bio: string;
//  bio2: string;
//  bio3: string;
// }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmANEcnA1SQK5kBG0LYr2BYA-NVr0QzVsKwAmcTTqMA3LJEBmJZLUEAvgQJgAngAcUAdWBgAFgDkcAeTNgRpADYAeACpNkANIQJsgQAB6QIAAmGMgA1sFYMMg+AHzIALwpyABk+MgA2gHIoIHBALoAtEo+ReXI+urG5ijoUNgg8pnI1naOIC5uOHDebR3+AORyE8gAPshTIvITqU2mFsgAwjgIUBCQvi3pWYTEBahQWBZQpiW4CSZJKS1VNS3nl9em5eqNRuutTA4TTdbYgXb7CBeMY4VZAA)